# Sniffing Tool Using Monitor Mode

Tags: penetration-test, sniffer, sniffing

As I understand it (fix me if I am wrong), there are two main ways of sniffing traffic from my wifi.

1. I can use ARP Spoofing, to poison a device on my network then capture all of its communication.
2. I can take my NIC to monitor mode, thus sniff all of the traffic.

As I see it, the second mode (monitor mode) is better than the first method (ARP spoofing), as there is no need to poison the network, it doesn't slow the victim's traffic and is less detectable (if I don't want to alter the network packets, only sniff).

As I looked around I found two great tools for sniffing (among many others, these two looked the simplest for me): Bettercap & XeroSploit.

The downside of these two tools is that (as far as I understand) they use ARP spoofing as their sniffing mode.

**So this is my actual question:**

Is there a **simple tool** (Simpler than using the whole airocrack suite) like bettercap or xerosploit which uses the network card's **monitor mode** ?

Comment: I am sorry but product recommendations are off topic here as they can get out of date pretty quickly.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Listening to Wifi signals or listening to network traffic?

Comment: I am trying to capture all traffic in order to sniff out sessions and credentials